# How to show that a function on a partition is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $\{A,B\}$ is a partition of a topological space $X$ and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a map to another space $Y$. Can you help me prove that if the restrictions $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are both continuous, then $f$ is continuous?

My definitions are as follows:

- $\{A,B\}$ is a *partition* of a topological space $X$, it's a pair of non-empty subsets of $X$ such that $X=A\cup B, A\cap B = \emptyset $, both $A$ and $B$ are open in $X$
- $f|_A$ is the restriction of $f$ to $A$, it's the map $f|_A: A\rightarrow Y$, defined by $(f|_A)(a)=f(a)$ for every $a\in A$

Comment: Your question is closely related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315110/functions-from-disjoint-unions/315115#315115), though not quite a duplicate (imo). $\{A,B\}$ is a partition of a topological space $X$ if and only if $X$ is topologized as the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show that the preimage of an open set is open.  If $O \subseteq Y$ is open then show that the preimage $f^{-1}(O)$ is equal to $(f|_A)^{-1}(O) \cup (f|_B)^{-1}(O)$.  Then use continuity of the restriction to show that each of the sets in that union is open in $A$ (or $B$) and hence open in $X$.